# Sum and difference equal to squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can anyone help me to find the integer solutions of these equations? 
\begin{align}
(w^2-r^2)+(s^2-k^2)&=t_1^2\\ 
(w^2-r^2)-(s^2-k^2)&=t_2^2 
\end{align}
It can be written as
\begin{align}
a+b&=t_1^2 \\
a-b&=t_2^2
\end{align}

Comment: Any odd number can be written as the difference of two squares, so for some $t_1$ an $t_2$, is it really easy.

Comment: Which of $w,r,s,k,t_1,t_2$ are considered given, which are you solving for?

Comment: All are variables, I want to solve it for all of them.

Comment: One solution is $w=\pm3,r=\pm2,s=\pm2,k=0,t_1=\pm3,t_2=\pm1$.

Comment: Thanks, what I want the complete solution, if possible :)

Comment: Finding all solutions involves factoring every integer in all possible ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one set of solutions. Let $t_1,t_2$ be arbitrary positive odd integers. Then $(t_1^2-t_2^2)/2$ is a multiple of 4, so you can solve $s^2-k^2=(t_1^2-t_2^2)/2$ by the usual method for expressing a number as a difference of two squares, and $(t_1^2+t_2^2)/2$ is odd, so similarly you can solve $w^2-r^2=(t_1^2+t_2^2)/2$.

You know how to express a given number $n=pq$ as a difference of 2 squares?

Here's how. If $n$ is odd, or if it is a multiple of 4, then it can be written as $pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are both even or both odd. Then $$n=\left({p+q\over2}\right)^2-\left({p-q\over2}\right)^2$$

EDIT (to do the case where the $t_i$ are even). If the $t_i$ are both even, and if they are both multiples of 4, or if neither one is a multiple of 4, then again $(t_1^2-t_2^2)/2$ is a multiple of 4, so you can solve $s^2-k^2=(t_1^2-t_2^2)/2$ by the method above for expressing a number as a difference of two squares; now $(t_1^2+t_2^2)/2$ is also a multiple of 4, so similarly you can solve $w^2-r^2=(t_1^2+t_2^2)/2$.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. I don't know how to do it. Can you show it to me?

Comment: Thanks, but you're assuming that t_1 and t_2 are odd. I want the opposite¡... I need two variables multiple of 4.

Comment: The techniques are all there, in what I've written for the odd case (and, if you wanted $t_1,t_2$ even --- WHT DIDN'T YOU SAY SO?).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are looking for some kind of a parametric solution. I can get you half-way there and give you parametric solution for $t_1$, $t_2$, $w$ and $r$.  Imposing the condition for $s$ and $k$ is harder and I have to think a bit. Hope that getting you this far helps.

Clearly
$$
t_1^2-t_2^2 = w^2 - r^2
$$
Factoring and rearranging (standard trick to convert quadratic to linear)
$$
\frac{t_1-t_2}{w-r} = \frac{t_1+t_2}{w+r}
$$
Call the common ratio $u/v$. This gives 4 *linear equations* in 4 unknowns
$$
\begin{align}
t_1-t_2 &= \alpha u &
w-r &= \alpha v\\
w+r &= \beta u & t_1+t_2 &= \beta v
\end{align}$$
You can solve for $t_1$, etc. and impose parity conditions to ensure that when dividing by $2$, the numerator is even.
$$\begin{align}
t_1 &= \frac{\alpha u + \beta v}{2} & t_2 &= \frac{\beta v - \alpha u}{2} \\
w &= \frac{\alpha v + \beta u}{2} & t_2 &= \frac{\beta u - \alpha v}{2} \\
\end{align}$$

Substitute in the original to get a condition for $s^2-k^2$ and proceed as
$$
s^2-k^2 =\left(\frac{\beta v - \alpha u}{4}\right)^2$$

Rest of the calculation is same, i.e. parametrize
$$
4 \frac{s-k}{\beta v - \alpha u} = \frac{\beta v - \alpha u}{(s+k)} $$
Only tricky part is you will have two equations for $\beta v$ and $\alpha u$ and you have to reconcile those. I will leave it up to you.